# react - .include return unexpected result

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an string array with below value

```
const lists = ["EH-AA","EH-BB","EH-CC"]
```

I tried to use below code and I expect this statement return true.

```
lists.includes('EH-')
```

But it returns false actually.
How should I modify the condition statement so that it will return true

Comment: what is `list`? Is it a string that looks like an array, or is it an array containing 3 strings? Please edit your question to format that line of code because it changes the whole meaning of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how `includes` works, it checks the array for that exact value. You need to loop over each item in the list and check if that item has that substring. You can do that with `.some`:

```
lists.some(item => item.includes('EH-'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also *join* the array and then check if it *includes* the specified *string*.

```js
const lists = ['EH-AA', 'EH-BB', 'EH-CC'];

const checkForStr = (arr, str) =>
   arr.join(',').includes(str);

console.log(checkForStr(lists, 'EH-'));
console.log(checkForStr(lists, 'random'));
```